# UTF-8 dotless i in cmd

Tags: r, cmd, utf-8, locale

I have an R script which was coded in utf-8. While running it in Rstudio, there is no problem with the Turkish characters. However, when I try to run it from cmd it throws an error:

> Columns `ÜrünAçiklama`, and `HataTanimi` don't exist.

It gives this error because my dataframe has the columns '`ÜrünAçıklama`' and '`HataTanımı`'.

As you can see, there is no problem with the characters "Ü,ü,Ç" but there is a problem with dotless i (ı). I run the script with this line in cmd

```
Rscript --encoding="UTF-8" myscript.r
```

my OS is windows10

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
An example should be fine.
[Here is my dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aOabkm18Q8dOWY0zCuXXd_Cnp03Hhj8j/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102294622834453385199&rtpof=true&sd=true). When I try to delete duplicate lines, I cannot reach the columns contain dotless i. You can try it in your own cmd with the following script.

```
library(readxl)

rm(list = ls())
shell("cls") 

df <- read_excel("stackoverflow.xlsx")
df$ÜrünNo
df$ÜrünAçıklama
df$HataTanımı
df$HataZamanı

df_nd <- df[!duplicated(df[,c("ÜrünNo","ÜrünAçıklama","HataZamanı")]),]
```

Also here is my CMD output:

```
[1] 1 2 3 3 4
[1] "X" "Y" "Z" "Z" "Q"
[1] "A" "B" "C" "C" "D"
[1] 10 11 12 12 13
Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
x Columns `ÜrünAçiklama` and `HataZamani` don't exist.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-df[!duplicated(df[, c("ÜrünNo", "ÜrünAçiklama", "HataZamani")])]
  2. +-tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(...)
  3. +-base::duplicated(df[, c("ÜrünNo", "ÜrünAçiklama", "HataZamani")])
  4. +-df[, c("ÜrünNo", "ÜrünAçiklama", "HataZamani")]
  5. \-tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(df, , c("ÜrünNo", "ÜrünAçiklama", "HataZamani"))
  6.   \-tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location(...)
  7.     +-tibble:::subclass_col_index_errors(...)
  8.     | \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  9.     \-vctrs::vec_as_location(j, n, names)
 10.       \-vctrs `<fn>`()
 11.         \-vctrs:::stop_subscript_oob(...)
 12.           \-vctrs:::stop_subscript(...)
 13.             \-rlang::abort(...)
Execution halted
```

As you can see, I can reach columns one by one, however when I try to delete duplicate line it just says columns do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was making some research, I encountered this sentence.

`R 4.2 for Windows will support UTF-8 as native encoding, which will be a major improvement in encoding support, allowing Windows R users to work with international text and data.`

Later, I just realized I was using 4.1. Updating R is the easiest and the fastest solution. Sorry for the inconvience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that utf-8 is neither locale independent nor representation independent. e.g. you can be using dotless i char in your script but the dataset might have saved i+a dotless modifier. Those will show as different in direct comparison.

Before comparing utf-8 strings you should use special libraries for it. or [normalize](https://rdrr.io/cran/utf8/man/utf8_normalize.html) it beforehand.